# in mysql, is there a way to not display a column after using *, like excluding the following column?

Tags: mysql, select

I have many columns in my table, so my query will look really messy if I use select......(all the columns). Can I use t.* and then say excluding this column?

Comment: In short : no. Thats not how it works

Comment: No, there is no way, in fact it is not good practice to use select * in your queries(any change in the table will affect your code).

Answer (score 2):

No, asterisks means `ALL`. Do not use `*` when you want to exclude some columns. The columns you want to include are only those that are specified in the SELECT query. Otherwise, if they are not in the `SELECT` statement, they are excluded.